# Python regex to remove two digit number in between strings

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have a String input and I need to remove two digit numbers from the string, wherever it appears.

Example:

`str = "abcdef12efgh abc12 abc12345defg 12 12abc abc123"`

The required output should be:

`abcdefefgh abc abc12345defg abc abc123`

I am able to remove the two digits prefixed/suffixed by '<*space*>', but not 'abcdef12efgh'.

Is there a regex for doing this? Or should I iterate through the string and remove the two digit numbers  checking if the string has non-numeric character before/after it.

Answer (score 4):

This might work.  `(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)`